# Customize Picker View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uipickerview

How to create Customized UIPicker View in iphone.I want to customize the background Color,Style of wheel.I also want to customize the different row's selection.How it will be done.
Can Anyone help me
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change change the view of the rows as Gypsa stated.

However if you want to change the appearance of the UIPickerView, laying out a transparent png on top of it is your best bet. Just make sure you disable user interactions on the png, so that you can interact with the wheel.

Below screenshots are from my latest app.

Good luck.

Nib without the skin:

[image: Nib without the skin]

Nib with the skin:

[image: Nib with the skin]

Final app:

[image: Final app]

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
Use this method to customize your pickerview:-

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
}
```

This is the delegate method which is called when picker view loaded or reloads